# Extracting trimmed data from string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have text formatted like this

```
address = "street: street A city: City B floor:"
```

I want to extract the street, city and floor from the address. Every one of this values can be blank.

```
>>> address_pattern = re.compile(
...     r'street:\s?(?P<street>.*)\s?'
...     r'city:\s?(?P<city>.*)\s?'
...     r'floor:\s?(?P<floor>.*)\s?'
... )
>>> address_pattern.search(address).groups()
('street A ', 'City B ', '')
```

As you can see there is a whitespace at the end of the strings which I am trying to avoid.

Obviously the simple solution here would be to `strip` the white space but where is the fun in that? If It's also possible to make it return `None` for empty string that would be great

Comment: How it would return `None`? If you change `r'floor:\s?(?P<floor>.*)\s?'` to `r'floor:\s?(?P<floor>.+)\s?'`, the whole regx will fail.

Comment: If you change your groups to non-greedy it will give expected results. Change `(?P<street>.*)` to `(?P<street>.*?)` etc.

Comment: Great ! This is what i was missing, making the group non greedy.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *non-greedy* operators for the matched groups, and greedy operators for matching the whitespace at the end:

```
>>> address_pattern = re.compile(
...     r'street:\s?(?P<street>.*?)\s*'
...     r'city:\s?(?P<city>.*?)\s*'
...     r'floor:\s?(?P<floor>.*?)\s*'
... )
>>> address_pattern.search(address).groups()
('street A', 'City B', '')
>>>
```